# Write second Header and Merge Cells using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

All,

I have written a script to write header and data into a excel sheet. But my actual requirement is to write sub header as well and need to merge the cells from the 2nd row.

```py
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import time
# Creating a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
column_list = df

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=2, header=False, index=False)

# Get workbook and worksheet objects
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

header_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 12, 'color' : 'white', 'fg_color': '#00007f','bold': True, 'border' : 1})

for idx, val in enumerate(column_list):
    worksheet.write(0, idx, val, header_fmt)

worksheet.write(1, 1, 'Sample', header_fmt)

font_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 9 })

worksheet.set_column('A:C', None, font_fmt)
worksheet.set_row(0, None, header_fmt)

writer.save()
```

**EDIT:**

Expected Output:
[image: 1]

There are 4 sections in the expected output, all of them are from different Dataframes. I need to merge all those Dataframes' output into a single sheet as shown in the image.

Comment: For subheading you can use `pandas.MultiIndex` [(docs)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html). For the second part of your question can you provide a small example of how you'd like to merge your data?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Is this what you want?

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import time
# Creating a dataframe                                                                                                                                       
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
column_list = df

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter engine.                                                                                                      
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=2, header=False, index=False)

# Get workbook and worksheet objects                                                                                                                         
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

header_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 12, 'color' : 'white', 'fg_color': '#00007f','bold': True, 'border' : 1})

merge_format = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center'})

worksheet.merge_range('A2:C2', 'Sample', merge_format)

for idx, val in enumerate(column_list):
        worksheet.write(0, idx, val,header_fmt)                                                                                                

        font_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 9 })

        worksheet.set_column('A:C',None, font_fmt)
        worksheet.set_row(0,None, header_fmt)

        writer.save()
```

Comment: you can see 4 sections in the expected output, all of them are from different Dataframe, i need to merge all those Dataframe output into a single sheet as described in the attached format.